# Parsing CNAME, NS in DNS answer

Tags: c, dns, compression, cname

I have the following code that checks the query type in the DNS Response, and then further print it accordingly. I need a way to parse CNAME and NS using the parameters given but am unable to do so. Here `tmp` is a variable that is defined as `tmp = (u_char *)(dpkt->payload + 12);` and `dns_label_to_str` is a function to convert DNS Name in string format defined as : `*dns_label_to_str(u_char **label, u_char *dest,size_t dest_size,const u_char *payload,const u_char *end)`

**Code:**

```
   switch (qtype) {
            case 1: /* A */
                    data = inet_ntop(AF_INET, tmp, dbuf, BUFSIZ);
            break;
            case 2:  /* NS */
            case 5:  /* CNAME */
            case 12: /* PTR */
                    data = (char *)dns_label_to_str(
                            &tmp, (u_char *)dbuf, BUFSIZ,
                            dpkt->payload, tmp + len
                    );
            break;
            case 10: /* NULL */
                    data = "NULL";
            break;
            case 15: /* MX (16-bit priority / label) */
                    i = snprintf(dbuf, 7, "%u ", ntohs(*(uint16_t *)tmp));
                    tmp += 2;
                    data = (char *)dns_label_to_str(
                            &tmp, (u_char *)(dbuf + i), BUFSIZ - i,
                            dpkt->payload, tmp + len - 2
                    );
                    data = dbuf;
            break;
            case 16: /* TXT (1 byte text length / text) */
                    if (*tmp <= len && tmp + len < end) {
                            memcpy(dbuf, tmp+1, *tmp);
                            dbuf[*tmp+1] = '\0';
                    } else *dbuf = '\0';
                    data = dbuf;
            break;
            case 17: /* AAAA */
                    data = inet_ntop(AF_INET6, tmp, dbuf, BUFSIZ);
            break;
            default:
                    /* Ignore unhandled RR types */
                    *dbuf = '\0';
                    data = dbuf;
    }

    /* Print the output. */
    printf("%ld %-5s %-30s %s\n", hdr->ts.tv_sec,
           dns_types[qtype], label, data);

ret:
    return 0;
}
```

If somebody could help on how I can get the CNAME when `qtype == 5` would be helpful. Thanks in advnce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data at `dpkt->payload + 12` is the *Question Section*, i.e. a copy of what was in the original request, and will comprise an (uncompressed) label known as `QNAME` and followed by the 16-bit `QTYPE` and `QCLASS` fields.

Only after that will you start to find the response data, each record of which follows this structure from [RFC 1035](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt), section 4, which I strongly suggest you read before going any further:

```
                                1  1  1  1  1  1
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3  4  5
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                                               |
/                                               /
/                      NAME                     /
|                                               |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                      TYPE                     |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                     CLASS                     |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                      TTL                      |
|                                               |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                   RDLENGTH                    |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--|
/                     RDATA                     /
/                                               /
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

Note that the data structure in the Question Section is identical to the first three fields of the above.

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear to me what the `dns_label_to_str` function does, but the most likely meaning of the parameters is:

- **`label`**: Pointer to a pointer.  `*label` initially points to the start of the name in the packet, and is updated to point to the next byte after the name in the packet.
- **`dest`**: Address of the destination buffer.  (This could be a string (text format) or an uncompressed name (wire format).
- **`dest`**: Length of the destination buffer.  Depending on the output format of the function, this should be at least 256 (wire format) or at least 1024 (text format, due to escaping).  Of course, the destination buffer must be large enough, t oo.
- **`payload`**: Pointer to the start of the *entire* DNS packet (*not* the data of the current resource record!).
- **`end`**: Pointer to one past the last byte in th entire DNS packet.

The reason why functions like `dns_label_to_str` need to refer to the entire packet is DNS label compression: names can contain a compression reference which points to another, earlier place in the packet, reusing the tail of another name in the packet, at a smaller offset. These references will never point within the resource record data because for CNAME records, it contains only a single name: if compression is used, the name tail must come from somewhere else.

**EDIT** We have a bit of a debate in the comments about forward compression pointers.  BIND 9 rejects them, but a lot of other implementations accept them.

Comment: the tail must come from somewhere else _earlier in the packet_.

Comment: @Alnitak The specification is slightly vague (it says *prior*), and most implementation support arbitrary jumps.

Comment: BIND doesn't support arbitrary jumps, and there's also been consensus discussion on this point at IETF when I wrote RFC 5625.  "Prior" is IMHO not in the slightest bit vague.

Comment: Very odd. If I didn't botch things, `forward-compression.caq.enyo.de` should have a forward compression pointer, and unbound 1.6.0 does *not* accept it. But I think our BIND-4/8-based stub resolver would accept it. I thought the BIND 8 `libbind` code was more influential, but you are right that most DNS servers do not seem to accept it. Will edit my answer.

Comment: it's quite possible that the non-ISC fork of `libresolv` that's in glibc does accept it.

Comment: `libbind` from BIND 8 and shipped with BIND 9 for a while had the same behavior in this regard. But I found the problem. My initial test domain resulted in an unexpected RDATA end. `forward-compression-2.caq.enyo.de` doesn't have this problem, and it's accepted by many more resolvers, but not BIND 9.